# Backbone search conditions

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a Backbone collection that contains a canvas X and Y coordinates and its width and height(rect). When I click on the canvas element, I have to search within a model if the click coordinates are between `Xcoordinate + width` and `Ycoordinate+height`, but I cannot find a way to search the collection with `>` or `<` conditions.

Is it possible to search a Backbone collection using those conditions? `collection.where` only allows `=` condition.

**Model**

```
Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        LayoutConfigurationId: 0,            
        Xcoord : 0,
        Ycoord : 0,            
        Width : 0,             
        Height : 0            
    },
    initialize: function (model) {
        contextMicro.clearRect(model.Xcoord-3, model.Ycoord-3, model.Width+6, model.Height+6);

        contextMicro.beginPath();
        contextMicro.rect(model.Xcoord, model.Ycoord, model.Width, model.Height);
        contextMicro.fillStyle = 'red';
        contextMicro.fill();
        contextMicro.lineWidth = 2;
        contextMicro.strokeStyle = 'black';
        contextMicro.stroke();

    }
});
```

**Collection**

```
 var Collection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    defaults: {
        model: Model
    },
    model: MicrophoneModel,       

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone [proxies a lot of Underscore functions](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods) into collections and notably [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) that allows you to write any filtering function you can think of.

For example, to get a list of all models that contain a given point x,y:

```
var c = new Backbone.Collection([
    {Xcoord:10, Ycoord:10, Width:10, Height:10},
    {Xcoord:20, Ycoord:20, Width:10, Height:10}
]);

var x = 15, y = 15;
var found = c.filter(function(m) {
    return (m.get('Xcoord')<x) && ((m.get('Xcoord')+m.get('Width'))>x)
       &&  (m.get('Ycoord')<y) && ((m.get('Ycoord')+m.get('Height'))>y);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/wa5xshoa/